# How to reduce deadlocks on select statement

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, deadlock

Can someone know how to fix this problem? When I trace the error. I saw a piece of code calling this query.

> SqlException : Transaction (Process ID 57) was deadlocked on lock

```
SELECT A.[CallID]
FROM dbo.[Calls] A WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Issues] B WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.[CallID] = B.[CallID]
WHERE A.[AddedByUserID] = @UserID
  AND A.[EndTime] IS NULL
  AND DATEDIFF(d,A.AddedOn,GETDATE()) <= 1
```

My understanding with `(NOLOCK)` is to prevent deadlock. But why am I encountering this error?

Comment: First of all `WITH NOLOCK` is not magic wand that removes your concurrency problem. Second it may cause **dirty reads** . Lastly `WITH (NOLOCK)` can be blocked with `SCHEMA STABILITY LOCK` when DDL occurs.

Comment: You should also look at the locking & reading patters of the SQLs involved. Indexing might fix your issues, and so can changing the SQL. NOLOCK can cause bigger problems that deadlocks depending on what this data is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to turn on [read committed snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx) so that `select` should not take any locks and get consistent reads.